# Cubic Congruence Solutions

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, congruences

While I was reading a paper on number theory, there was a claim which wasn't prove there and I couldn't find a way to justify it. The claim is as follows

For a prime $p$, when $p\nmid a$, the number of incongruent solutions to $x^3\equiv a \mod p^3$ is $O(1)$.

Is there an elementary proof of this?

reference to the paper (page 28): Brüdern, Jörg. A note on cubic exponential sums. Seminaire de Theorie des Nombres, Paris, 199091, 2334,
Progr. Math., 108, Birkhäuser Boston, Boston, MA, 1993.

Comment: So $f(z)$ is $O(1)$ means $f$ is bounded right?  What is $z$ in this case?  $x$, $a$ or $p$?

Comment: Yes that's right. $x$ is our variable, $p$ is fixed so $z$ in this would be $a$.

Comment: Something seem strange now that I think about it better.  If $p$ is fixed then the number of solutions is finite, so bounded, so $O(1)$.  The only thing that can really go to infinity then is $p$, so I am guessing this means to consider the asymptotic in terms of $p$, not $x$ or $a$.

Comment: Otherwise maybe all it is saying is that the ring $\mathbb Z/p^3\mathbb Z$ is finite.  Could that be what they mean?

Comment: It may help if you include a reference to the paper... especially if it's on the arxiv and easy for everyone to access.

Comment: My apologies. Yes you're right. $p$ is growing and that's what is needed in the paper.

Comment: @TravisJ, I edited the question with the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first use this fact that the congruent
$$
x^3\equiv a\pmod p
$$
Has at most three solutions, hence the congruent
$$
x^3\equiv a\pmod {p^3}
$$
has a bounded numbers (independent of $p$) of solutions according to Hensel's lemma.

Comment: The devil is in the details. Could you explain how the second equation has finite solution? How exactly do you use Hensel's lemma?

Comment: WLoG suppose that $p>3$ now If $x$ is a solution for the first equation, then because $(x^3-a)'=3x^2$ is not divisible by $p$ we deduce that the number of solutions for the first equation is same as the equation $x^3\equiv a\pmod {p^2}$ now use Hensel's lemma once more to deduce the theorem...